# Installing plugin into eclipse using command line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an update site, and got the directory which contains the features and plugins

How to install the plugin in eclipse application using the command line ?
I want to automate this process

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you automate the installation of Eclipse plugins with command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163970/how-do-you-automate-the-installation-of-eclipse-plugins-with-command-line)

Comment: Decent write-up with screenshots here: http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2012/10/installing-eclipse-features-via-the-command-line/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can invoke [p2 director application](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) using something like this:

```
eclipsec.exe
   -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
   -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/
   -installIU org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group
   -destination d:/eclipse/
   -profile SDKProfile
```

Here is also link to [p2 wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_director_application).

Comment: How it will know about my feature while I don't refer to its path ?

Comment: You will specify installIU for your feature and repository location, e.g. using file: protocol.