# How to install list of eclipse plugins from a script?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I need a way to setup a highly customized eclipse coding environment in a fully unattended way from a script in linux.  The customized eclipse environment requires the installation of about 10 different plugins from various sources (protobuf, pydev, cmakeed, openinterminal, egit, yaml, webpageeditor, etc).  Doing this manually each time with the gui takes 20-30 minutes.  I want to automate the install of plugins in a script so anyone running linux can recreate my eclipse environment with a custom set of plugins without human interaction.  Anyone have advice about how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you automate the installation of Eclipse plugins with command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163970/how-do-you-automate-the-installation-of-eclipse-plugins-with-command-line)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here are the command line snippets to install some of my favorite plugins (tested on Eclipse Indigo 3.7)... The trick is to figure out the value of the "installIU" parameter for the package... The Eclipse GUI will show this if you click on "more" link when the desired package is selected in the installer window.

[**cmakeed** - CMake editor](http://cmakeed.sourceforge.net/)

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/,http://cmakeed.sourceforge.net/eclipse/ -installIU com.cthing.cmakeed.feature.feature.group
```

[**OpenInTerminal** - Add option in context menu](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-openinterminal/)

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/,http://eclipse-openinterminal.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/site/ -installIU OpenInTerminal.feature.group
```

[**protobuf-dt** - Google Protobuffer editor](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-dt/)

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/,http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/,http://protobuf-dt.googlecode.com/git/update-site -installIU com.google.eclipse.protobuf.feature.group
```

[**yedit** - YAML Editor](http://code.google.com/p/yedit/)

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/,http://dadacoalition.org/yedit -installIU org.dadacoalition.yedit.feature.group
```

[**shelled** - Bash Script Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/)

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/,http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates/,https://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/files/shelled/update/ -installIU net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group
```

**Web Page Editor**

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ -installIU org.eclipse.jst.webpageeditor.feature.feature.group
```

**Pydev**
Pydev is tricky because it requires installing a certificate first... Here's a script that automates that step:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Add PyDev's certificate to Java's key and certificate database
# Certificate file here: http://pydev.org/pydev_certificate.cer
import os, sys, pexpect, urllib2
def main():
  # NOTE: You may have to update the path to your system's cacerts file
  certs_file = '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/security/cacerts'  
  pydev_certs_url = 'http://pydev.org/pydev_certificate.cer'
  print "Adding pydev_certificate.cer to %s" % (certs_file)
  pydev_cert = open('pydev_certificate.cer', 'w')
  pydev_cert.write(urllib2.urlopen(pydev_certs_url).read())
  pydev_cert.close()
  cmd = "keytool -import -file ./pydev_certificate.cer -keystore %s" % (certs_file)
  child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
  child.expect("Enter keystore password:")
  child.sendline("changeit")
  if child.expect(["Trust this certificate?", "already exists"]) == 0:
    child.sendline("yes")
  try:
    child.interact()
  except OSError:
    pass  
  print "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Then you can run:

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/,http://pydev.org/updates/ -installIU org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group
```

Comment: This also works in windows, just append '.exe' to the path to the eclipse executable. As for the python script, it would have to be run with python or modified as `/usr/bin/python` won't work on most setups and the pexpect module doesn't currently work on windows. Both of these issues may be resolved with cygwin, I don't use it, so I can't confirm.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [p2 director application](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) to install Eclipse features with a script.  Here are some [more](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_director_application/Examples/Install_into_eclipse_using_SDKProfile) [links](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/04/04/installing-eclipse-features-via-the-command-line-with-the-p2-director/) that may help.